# How do you put out a grease fire?

Tags: food-safety

I recently had a grease fire - the pan caught on fire from a little fat that spilled over the skillet. Is there a safe, quick way to put out a fire like this?

Comment: If this happens frequently, e.g. more than once in your life time, then I say it worth investing some money on a fire extinguisher.

Comment: @user3528438 In any situation where you aren't trying to trade your home for insurance money, you should have an extinguisher (edit: or a pile of accessible salt) ahead of time as cheap insurance against burning everything down and harming loved ones and innocents. It doesn't matter how often you think the event might occur: accidents are by their nature accidental and you'll need to replace the extinguisher after a single use anyway. It isn't like it will ever pay off in any way except stopping that first fire.

Answer (score 40):

Steps to put out a grease fire

1. **Turn off the source of heat**. If the burner / element controls are behind the fire, turn off the gas main or cut electricity at the circuit breaker. Turn off any fan blowing or pulling air around the fire.
2. **Do NOT pour water on it**.
3. Let me say that again: **DO NOT pour water on it**!
4. **Attempt to remove all oxygen from the flame**. You can cover it with its lid, with another pot or wok, or with a baking pan, anything nonflammable. Fire blankets, however, usually *cannot* handle grease fires.
5. If you can't cover it, **dump baking soda on it**... but you need *lots* of it. Some people below had success with salt. Heated baking soda releases carbon dioxide, starving the fire of air if it's cool enough that it won't reignite. Salt just absorbs the heat and smothers it like a lid. *Do not* use flour or any flammable powders. *Do not* throw the baking soda or salt in a way that might spread the fire.
6. Secret step number 6: If all else fails, **use a fire extinguisher**. Class K extinguishers are low pressure and meant for grease fires. Aim any other kind of high-pressure extinguisher indirectly so that it won't spread the fire. If the fire seems contained by step 4 or 5, get the extinguisher ready but don't use it if the fire is dying out on its own.

Comment: For home cooking, this is the right answer.
For anything bigger, you want a halon extinguisher (preferably an automatic one) or some Aqueous Film Forming Foam (AFFF).
It's amazing what you learn in the navy, isn't it?

Comment: @Carmi : You can't get halon in all areas.  As a backup, you want something that's rated well for 'class B' fires, but I'd also recommend bouncing it off of the wall rather than spraying straight at the fire, to disipate the energy and not push the fire around, making it larger.

Comment: @Tree77 : a word of warning; I was cooking with my neighbor when he had a greese fire in the burner, and we tried covering it with a lid over the burner;  It **did not** work, because on his stove, there was enough of an air gap from under the burner (the whole top of the stove lifted up so you could clean underneath) that the fire kept going, and burned up his stove.  If we had gone straight for the fire extinguisher, rather than smothering, we might've been able to save the stove.

Comment: Surely "fire blanket" would be an option before extingusher...

Comment: @Joe: Obviously, you're right, and not everything is correct everywhere. The main point is that if the fire is hot enough to be burning grease, you can't dissipate the heat fast enough, so you need to smother the fire with soemthing.
The advantage of halon is that once the fire is out and everything cools off, you can just vacuum the stuff away and it doesn't do any damage.
There is a whole art to putting out fires by spraying net to them to dissipate heat and avoid causing thermal shcok to things, but that takes serious training.

Comment: I only keep a single box of baking soda in the kitchen - probably not enough for firefighting.  <br />Don't use flour instead of baking soda.  Flour can be quite flammable.

Comment: +1 for attempt to remove oxygen, 2 days ago this happened to me, the fire quickly went out on its own but if it had not, I had no baking soda and no fire extinguisher. Removing oxygen would have been my only option.

Comment: @KatieK haha I tried it with flour. Fortunately it didnt light and after the grease fire was out I had a big pile of smoldering flour and had to cover it with a wet towel (which I should have done in the first place).

Comment: @RowlandShaw Fire blankets may work, if you know how to apply them, but a [2014 test from a Belgian consumer organization](https://www.consumentenbond.nl/fornuis/blusdekens-in-de-fik-bij-frituurbranden) showed that 13 out 16 tested fire blankets sold commercially are not heavy duty enough for grease fires. They actually [recommended NOT using those](http://frituurbrand.nl/). (Sorry, all Dutch language links)

Comment: This answer misses: in a modern kitchen with an air extraction hood (it that  the correct English word?), switch that off. You don't want that excessive heat (or flames) drawn into your air channels.

Answer (score 18):

I'm an arson investigator and I give classes to businesses with our fire extinguisher demo. The participants must supply their own fire extinguishers but they get to practice using them in a controlled environment. Here's the rules for kitchen/grease fires that I teach. When you have a grease fire the first step is to cover the pan. If the controls are on the front of the stove you should turn off the burner, but if the controls are on the back of the stove you don't want to risk a burn reaching for it until you've covered it. Next step...nothing. Leave it alone and let it cool up for quite a while. NEVER EVER EVER move the pan. Even after you've covered it. I can't tell you how many structure fires I've investigated because someone tried to move a burning pan of grease off of the burner. It's almost impossible to move a pan full of any liquid without sloshing or spilling it, then add the excitement of the fire and you're almost guaranteed to end up spreading grease everywhere. Grease and oil heat up to over 300 degrees F. so it will take quite some time to cool off but don't risk moving it. Keep it covered and it will cool off on it's own.

There have been several people mentioning all the "home remedies" to extinguishing grease fires. Never use the wet towel method. Water boils at 212 degrees F. and cooking oils are commonly used at temperatures well above that. The oil will quickly boil off the water in the towel and then you will be left with an oil soaked wick. Halon has been mostly restricted to a few specific fixed extinguishing systems and I haven't seen them used as portable fire extinguishers in a long time. Class B rated fire extinguishers probably won't be very effective due to the higher temperatures which is why Class K fire extinguishers have become the standard agent specifically for extinguishing grease fires. The extinguishing agent in Class K fire extinguishers can withstand the high temperatures and forms a soapy film on top of the grease, it acts like a lid restricting oxygen from the fuel. Class B fire extinguishers will work briefly but the high heat breaks down the agent before the grease can cool below it's ignition point and once the oxygen is allowed to mix with the grease vapors it will re-ignite. Dry Chemical fire extinguishers (not to be confused with dry powder which is for flammable metals) can work on grease fires, but as with most fire extinguishers the agent is expelled at high pressures that will usually splash the grease and spread the fire. Class K fire extinguishers expel the agent at much lower pressures which avoids the splashing effect. Water should never be used in a grease fire. Water boils at 212 degrees F. When it turns into a vapor it expands 1700 times its volume as liquid water. Since grease is well above this temperature when it is burning the water instantly boils and expands causing the grease to be thrown out of the container spreading the fire. Google some frozen turkey - turkey fryer videos to see examples of this.

Baking soda will work, if you can avoid splashing, which is why I don't recommend it. Dry Chemical fire extinguishers, commonly known as ABC fire extinguishers, usually have some form of sodium bicarbonate as the dry chemical agent. Never use flour, it's very flammable. I'm sure there are tons of YouTube videos of this for you to see. The problem with most powders are that when you get any substance in a small enough particle, lots of substances become flammable or explosive. 'Ladder 49' was based off of a grain silo fire which is a very real scenario. It was grain dust that was generated from pulverizing grain in the conveyor process of moving the grain around. Sugar is also explosive in dust form. Google the Georgia Imperial Sugar refinery explosion of 2008.

TL,DR:

1. Cover the fire with a lid or another pan to exclude oxygen from the grease vapors
2. Turn off the burner or heat source
3. Leave it alone until it has cooled off, Do not try to move it.
4. Class K fire extinguishers were designed specifically for grease fires and are the only fire extinguisher recommended for use on grease fires.
5. Don't use household powders, most are flammable/explosive when the particles are separated like they are when they are thrown. Google 'flour fireball'

Comment: I've never heard of a class K: is that perhaps the same as class F (I'm in Europe)?

Answer (score 15):

I had a grease fire years ago while using my first electric stove. I dumped most of a box of baking soda on it with no visible effect; my wife ran in and hit it with a Halon fire extinguisher, which actually spread the grease and fire against the wall behind the stove! I called 911, and the dispatcher told me to dump **salt** on the fire. I did - about a cup - and it killed the fire almost instantly.

Baking soda puts out fires by releasing carbon dioxide and smothering the fire, but if your fire is burning violently enough, the convection created by the fire pulls in enough oxygen to offset the smothering effect. Smothering with baking soda could work if you had a bucket of baking soda, but a little refrigerator-size box won't cut it, as I learned through experience. Salt, on the other hand, apparently is a great absorber of heat for its volume. It sucks so much heat out of the grease that it simply can't support combustion anymore.

Bottom line:

- Never, ever use a pressurized fire extinguisher on a grease fire.
- Baking soda is probably not going to do the trick.
- Salt is your friend.

It's been twenty-some years, and I've never had a kitchen fire since (knock on wood!), but I still make sure to have a box of salt within reach whenever I fry anything.

Comment: A fire extinguisher isn't necessarily bad, but you have to use it appropriately for the kind of fire you have. Standing right in front of a pan full of grease and shooting it with pressurized _anything_ will obviously spread it all over the place. You need to stand back and use the extinguisher to starve the fire. It may take a little longer than you'd expect.

Comment: But salt is 1) incredibly cheap 2) safe 3) almost magically fast.  Obviously if you haven't turned off the heat, the oil could flash again - but at least in my (one) experience, half a cup of salt killed the fire instantly.

Answer (score 7):

Daniel is right. Suffocate the fire. DO NOT DO NOT DO NOT attempt to pour water on it. The water will superheat and create a huge fireball of vaporized grease and steam. People have been seriously [injured](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOvdlVEN6wY).

Comment: Major +1 for the video.

Answer (score 7):

I like the [Mythbusters version](http://dsc.discovery.com/videos/mythbusters-greased-lightning/) of why you shouldn't do this better. (First 20 seconds of the video, for scary firey plume montage)

When you add water, it flashes instantly to steam and blows molten oil high into the air, where, suddenly in an O2 rich environment, it bursts into flame. Impressive, and something you never want to happen in your kitchen.

Buy yourself a high quality fire extinguisher, and learn how to turn off the electricity/gas at the source. You can try to smother it, but honestly I don't recommend it if it's anything to really worry about. Oil in a pan isn't going to burn *that* high. Oil accidentally knocked on the floor is going to burn your whole house.

Turn off the heat source, and wait until the flames subside. Do not move the pan. Do not put anything on or near it that may burn. Do not do anything that might splash oil out of the pan. When the oil is hot enough to burn, you don't want it out of the pan under ANY circumstances...It will IMMEDIATELY burst into flame.

Answer (score 6):

Smother with lid, fire blanket or *wet* (*wet* you plonker!) cloth. Then, yes, use the **extinguisher**.

On the extinguisher front:

Yes, you can use an extinguisher to put out grease fires, but be careful. There are different kinds of extinguishers. Check that the one in your kitchen (or the one you're likely to use) is the right kind *before* any kind of fire.

**Water extinguisher**: Fortunately there aren't too many of these around now. Water extinguishers should NEVER be used in a kitchen. Between grease fires and electrical fires, it's almost universally the wrong extinguisher to use.

**CO2 - (High pressure carbon dioxide) Extinguisher**: These are the most common you'll find, and recognizable by the big "horn" dispenser. CO2 extinguishers work by removing oxygen, but can disperse quite quickly. They are also under pressure, so don't get too close to the source of fire when using a CO2 extinguisher. You *don't* want to "blow" the oil out of the pan. The big plus with this type of extinguisher is that the CO2 evaporates (it makes a kind of CO2 snow) so very little damage is done other than damage caused by the fire. Caveat: These extinguishers can be useless outdoors, or in highly ventilated environments. CO2 is great for really small indoor fires before they get out control. The "snow" coming out the extinguisher is cold (think dry ice) and some stuff (especially electronics) doesn't like the extreme cold, but on balance it's the best indoor extinguisher, though like all pressurized extinguishers, dangerous if improperly sprayed directly at burning liquid.

**Dry-Powder Extinguisher (The powder is usually bicarb)**: These extinguishers works by removing the oxygen and smothering the fire. They are good for outdoors, and work on pretty much any kind of (small) fire, including kitchen fires and electrical fires. However, the retardant doesn't evaporate, and powder extinguishers do make a mess. A 9 kg extinguisher (typical size) contains 9 kg of bicarb. While these extinguishers have a "trigger nozzle", they are notoriously leaky, so  once started most of the 9 kg is going to be released. Also dry-powder extinguishers need regular (annual) servicing to prevent the contents from caking and rendering the extinguisher useless.

**Obscure extinguishers**: Halon and BCF extinguishers were popular because they have all the benefits of CO2, but aren't "cold," so they're a lot kinder to electronics. They're also CFCs, which have gone out of fashion for environmental reasons. And both are brutally expensive compared to CO2. Unless saving the electronics is critical, like say on a nuclear submarine, they're overkill for a home or office environment.

**Bottom line**: In a home situation I would recommend CO2 for most rooms, plus Dry-Powder for the kitchen.

Most importantly - if you use an extinguisher, remove the heat source as well. In the case of CO2 if the fuel is still hot, then it can reignite when the CO2 dissipates.

Lastly - after any extinguisher has been used - even for just a squirt - it *must* be replaced. Water and Dry Powder are "one-use" extinguishers, even with a trigger, and while control on a CO2 extinguisher is much better it *must, must, must* be replaced (recharged) after even a single use.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the wet cloth/tea towel trick. Fast, easy, safe and effective.

Comment: See [MikeJ's comment](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/35767/67) for a rebuttal to the wet towel suggestion ... it only works for really small fires, and if it's dripping wet, can make things worse.   (and this reminds me ... I need to recharge or replace my extinguishers)

Answer (score 3):

**Do not use water.**

You have to suffocate it.  Turn off the burner (obviously),  Find a tight fitting pan lid and put it over the flame tightly.  If it's on the stove and not in a pan, you can still use a pan lid to suffocate it, you just might have to get a little creative about how you cover it.  A pan, wok or any sturdy, non-flammable cover would work as well.  Anything that can cut off their air supply.

Fire extinguishers will work as well if it's too big to fit under a pan lid, pan or other handy cover.  If you don't have a fire extinguisher and it's that big... call 911 (or your location's equivalent), you're in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Smother the fire with a [fire blanket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_blanket) (or any sheet of fire retardant material)
2. Turn off power supply / gas
3. Leave the blanket in place and call help if necessary

Comment: See my comment under the top answer. For *grease* fires fire blankets are not recommended.

Comment: and to follow up on @user34961 the reason is—regardless of what your poster's art shows—almost none of them are actually strong enough to handle a pot full of grease fire on their own. Maybe they'd help if all you have is one plus a heavy-duty wok: use the upside-down wok to do most of the job and the blanket to help cut off air along the sides but not trying to handle the fire itself.

Answer (score 0):

when i had a fire like this i turned off the heat then pour salt over it. it sounds crazy but it worked.

Comment: Sorry you got downvoted for sharing good info when other bad advice about wet towels and fire blankets got upvoted. Generally you need to provide more context and, ideally, reliable sources like on Wikipedia.

Answer (score -2):

First of all try to stay calm so you can make sound decisions. I had a pan of bacon grease spill all over the bottom of my oven so i turned it off and figured it would burn off....that is until it started to get too big for comfort. Meanwhile, i quickly drenched and totally saturated several kitchen rags and towels, and carefully opened oven. With oven mittens i quickly removed the racks and without the racks in the way, took each corner of the kitchen towel and tried to lay it evenly over the bottom of the oven. Did that with two staurated towels and the fire went out instantly. I then removed towels and after my heart rate went back to normal, i turned the oven back on andmonitored that the fire would not come back. All was good. No fire came back.

Comment: This is a different kind of fire, so you are not answering the question. AND (!), as MikeJ writes in [his answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/35767/34961) you should NEVER USE the wet towel method on a grease fire in a pan. I therefore suggest this answer gets removed ASAP.

Comment: @user34961 It really isn't a different kind of fire. Bacon grease is just lard, which absolutely gets used in the same ways as oil and shortening. Hell, it's the reason grease fires are called grease fires instead of oil or fat fires. Otoh, yeah, David should've provided more context and gone out of his way to make it clear that this only works on small fires that can quickly be completely cut off from oxygen before they burn through the cloth... and several other techniques are better if at all possible since you're risking making things much worse.