# Should I polish a cast iron pan for use on a glass cooktop?

Tags: cast-iron, stove, glass

There was a [question asked here about using cast iron on glass top ranges](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4734/using-cast-iron-on-a-glass-range). In the responses, there was a link to an [article about cast iron equipment](http://theinductionsite.com/induction-cookware/Lodge/Lodge-cast-iron.shtml). Here is a quote.

> There is also an almost comically simple alternative for a more
>   permanent fix. It's one of those ideas like the safety pin or the
>   paper clip: blindingly obvious in hindsight, but not apparent at once.
>   Just sandpaper the pan or pot bottom smooth! Readers have reported to
>   us that they have done just that, with excellent results. We don't
>   have details, but we'd guess that two grades of sandpaper, a coarse
>   then a fine for polishing off, would do the job.

I am getting my first brand-new electric glass-top range, and I don't want to ruin it. The quote said they are guessing, but with Stack Exchange, there is no guessing just real experiences. **How do you polish the cast iron to make the bottom smoother?** Did you see an improvement?

Comment: Brand-new electric range = brand-new glass top electric range?

Comment: Yes. I updated the question text to clarify.

Comment: @Cascabel Isn't this a duplicate of the mentioned question? https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4734/using-cast-iron-on-a-glass-range

Comment: My question here is trying to get refinement, so no, it isn't a duplicate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be a short answer as there is not much to say:

I have used cast iron pans on my glass stove top for about five years, and the surface does not show any scratches or marks. I have not taken any special care to protect the surface, and certainly have not polished the iron.

Comment: To close the loop a little, I'd like to give an update. I have been using my new range for several weeks now with my cast iron, and I have not had any troubles.

Answer (score 1):

No, I haven't.  I admit, however, that it's only an induction hot-plate, and my main stove is resistive electric.  I also sometimes cook at my neighbor's house, and they have a a glass-topped electic stove and cast iron, and they don't polish theirs, either.  (so it's now been three years, and their two pans in heaviest rotation are Lodge cast iron skillets)

I personally haven't had any problems (other than the induction cooker heating up the aebelskiver pan differently than resistive electric).  I *do* change my behaviour, as I don't shake the pan on the stove without lifting (which I'll do at home).

We also both keep our pans well-seasoned, though, and that includes the bottom.  When I re-seasoned the poffertjes and aebelskiver pans (specifically for use on the induction cook top; the aebelskiver pan was new, the poffertjes pan hadn't been maintained), I gave them three cycles through the oven to make sure the bottoms were coated well.  This, however, caused me a little bit of a problem with the poffertjes pan, as the bottom wasn't entirely flat (just slightly convex), so it can walk a little bit as you're using it, and I have to keep pushing it back over the burner.

And I actually do have a piece of polished cast iron ... I don't remember how I came by it.  I think it was a friend's dad did it with some tools for buffing cars.  It's kinda strange looking, as it's not black ... it actually looks more orange-ish, like when you bake something on an aluminum tray, and the oil drips and leaves that annoying residue you can't get off easily.  I admit, I don't really use it, though ... it's more of a novelty.  I don't know if it'd go to black if I cooked with it more often.  (it's smaller, and not a size I'd typically use).

Comment: Are you saying that polishing isn't necessary if the cast iron is well seasoned? Or that polishing isn't desirable because it makes pans turn orange-ish? Otherwise it seems this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Sobachatina : I'm saying I haven't had any problems with glass cooktops with cast iron pans where the back is well seasoned.