# Is anyone aware of cast iron pots and pans that are enameled on the exterior with plain cast iron (no enamel, no non-stick) interiors?

Tags: equipment, cast-iron, induction

Looking for a brand of cast iron pans that is enameled on the outside, but with a bare iron interior. In other words **no enamel, no ceramic, no non-stick** on the inside. (so it is less likely to scratch an induction cooktop)

Comment: Many...very many. From £20 cheap to toe-curlingly expensive. You can get them anywhere - Aldi, Sainsbury's or any kitchen shop.

Comment: @Trish Le Creuset doesn’t make any cookware with uncoated interiors, that I’m aware of.

Comment: @DebbieM. I wish they did!

Comment: BeccaCooks where in the world are you located, there may be a local manufacturer someone knows about.

Comment: @Tetsujin I’m not seeing uncoated interiors on any enameled exterior cast iron.

Comment: @DebbieM. U.S. I will need to make some inquiries.

Comment: Le Creuset make exactly what you’re looking for, but there are many cheaper supermarket copies.

Comment: @Tetsujin regarding Le Creuset interiors, no unfinished pans are available in the US. There are a couple of pans that look like unfinished cast iron, but they actually have a matte black enamel coating.

Comment: Sure they’re not just ready-seasoned? Mine was.

Comment: @Tetsujin https://www.lecreuset.com/signature-skillet/LS2024.html or check Amazon.com or other high end kitchen product suppliers.

Comment: Enameling technology has traditionally prevented one-sided coatings because thermally-induced warping can damage the enamel. I assume it's possible to develop a functional pan without the enamel on the interior, but the results may be less consistently successful, and for the most part the point of enameling is to have the interior coated for easier use and cleanup. (That's also the point of seasoning a cast iron skillet, of course-- you always want the metal to have a coating of some sort.) See [here for protecting the glass from cast iron](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/76163).

Answer (score -1):

Staub has cast iron enameled outside and bare iron inside

Comment: Currently all of  Staub’s pots, pans & even cast iron skillets that appear bare inside, actually have a matte black enameled coating.