# Portable induction cooktop with cast iron pans, will using these together break or scratch the cooktop?

Tags: cast-iron, induction

I have been looking at buying an induction cooktop for quite some time.  Largely the part that has tipped the scales in my favor as of lately is that I would like to be able to use cast iron skillets regularly and my current situation does not allow for that.

I have read and seen some usage of cast iron skillets on these induction cooktops, but from what I have seen almost all of these are ceramic topped.  I thought ceramic topped cooktops and cast iron skillets were items that should not be used together.

Could someone please elaborate on the usage of these together?  Has anyone used these together and had no issues?

Comment: There's typically no problem.  See  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4734/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/22660/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/76163/67

Answer (score 3):

Induction tops are usually glass or ceramic, and they will scratch over time no matter what pans you use. Cast iron works very well on induction, and is inexpensive. It is heavy though, if you drop one on your induction top you could crack it.

Answer (score -1):

They are literally made for each other but when you buy your pan you should bring a straight edge with you. Manufacturers don't make many pans that have a flat bottom. And you want contact. Induction wants contact for its magnet. As for the glass it will get micro abrasions but that's life. They will happen regardless of which material you use.

Comment: -1, because induction is special for *not* needing contact.

Comment: also there are many pans with a flat bottom...